# nextpwa disable media download src in background

Tags: next.js, next-pwa

when using shadowwalker/nextpwa, media like video .mp4, or .mov, it's always download in background, how to disable workbox download media in background for mp4/mov?

[always download src media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tLia.png)

next.config.js :

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa")({
    dest: "public",
    register: true,
    disable: false,
    skipWaiting: true,
    reloadOnOnline: false,
});

module.exports = withPWA({
    reactStrictMode: true,
    generateEtags: false,
    images: {
        domains: [
            ...
        ],
    },
    async redirects() {
        return [
            ...
        ];
    },
});
```

how to disable download media in background nextpwa?